# Powershell NTFS ACL export to Excel Error

Tags: arrays, powershell, vbscript

I am having an issue with a script I wrote. Basically it reads a list of UNC paths from a file FolderList.txt
Pulls a ACL list from the file location and exports all that info out to an Excel. My first column is fine but the second is giving me an error message. I believe the reason is that I am trying to put to many lines of data or possible array type data into the second column. Please help I wave the white flag on this one.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$Excel = new-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $True
$Excel = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$Sheet = $Excel.Worksheets.Item(1)
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,1) = "Folder Name"
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,2) = "Folder Permissions"
$intRow = 2
$WorkBook = $Sheet.UsedRange
$WorkBook.Font.Bold = $True

$data = Import-Csv -Path C:\xPowerShellScripts\FolderList.txt -Header "Path" -Delimiter ","
foreach ($head in $data) 
{
$Permission = (Get-Acl $head.Path).Access | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 1) = $head.Path
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 2) = $Permission
$intRow = $intRow + 1
}

$WorkBook.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
$intRow = $intRow + 1
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1) = "Folder Permissons Report"
```

Comment: You're doing this the hard way. Give me a few minutes to write it up and I'll have an answer for you.

Comment: @WhiteHat He's already taken care of that, though there are other inherent issues with his script, but for his specific question that isn't the issue.

Comment: Please give us the error message :)

Comment: Hi JRN, I figured out how to get it to work with only a six character change :) Hope you like it

Comment: Regardless of what answer you take, you should consider that you are listing both Allow and Deny permissions indiscriminately. You should seriously consider piping `(Get-Acl $head.Path)` to `Where{$_.AccessControlType -eq 'Allow'}` so that you don't get the Deny listings.

Comment: That's a great idea, @TheMadTechnician.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue.

The error message:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
At line:18 char:1
+ $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 2) = $Permission
```

The offending line:

```
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 2) = $Permission
```

The reason for this is that you're trying to write a value `$Permission` which is actually an array of objects, all of which contain the information you want within their `Value` property.  Here's what $Permission actually looks like:

```
PS C:\temp> $Permission

Value                           
-----                           
BUILTIN\Administrators          
BUILTIN\Administrators          
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM             
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM             
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
BUILTIN\Users                   
BUILTIN\Users
```

The fix for this is to use `` -join "`n" `` to make one big cell with many line breaks in it, to contain all of the permissions in one taller than normal cell.

```
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 2) = $Permission.Value -join "`n"
```

The result:

[image]

If you'd like to also have a cloumn for users with access denied, use this instead. [Gist Link.](https://gist.github.com/1RedOne/76e5928925b11a8e42eb)

Comment: FoxDeploy: That is exactly what I knew the problem was I had no idea how to fix it. Thank you so much for you quick and concise answer. I was banging my head against the wall because for one I wasn't sure how to word it and I hate to give too much info because I risk creating a bias on the solution. Your the best thanks again.

Comment: I added some logic to add another column for Access Denied users, after @TheMadTechnician gabe me the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Stop doing it the hard way. Don't update cell by cell, collect all data, convert it to tab delimited CSV, and paste the whole thing into Excel.

So, for each item in `$Permission` you're going to make a `[PSCustomObject]` with the values that you want, and then we'll collect all of those in an array.

```
[array]$AllPerms = foreach ($head in $data) 
{
    (Get-Acl $head.Path).Access | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference | ForEach{
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Folder Name"=$Head.Path
            "Folder Permissions"=$_.value
        }
    }
}
```

That'll make an array of objects and each object will have the two properties that you are looking for in your columns. Now that we have the array we convert it to a tab delimited CSV and copy it to the clipboard.

```
$AllPerms | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInfo | Clip
```

Ok, now we paste it into the first cell of the worksheet:

```
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1).PasteSpecial() | Out-Null
```

And after that I'd take care of the formatting. So the whole thing looks like this in the end:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$Excel = new-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $True
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$Sheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

$data = Import-Csv -Path C:\xPowerShellScripts\FolderList.txt -Header "Path" -Delimiter ","

[array]$AllPerms = foreach ($head in $data) 
{
    (Get-Acl $head.Path).Access | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference | ForEach{
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Folder Name"=$Head.Path
            "Folder Permissions"=$_.value
        }
    }
}

$AllPerms | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInfo | Clip

$Sheet.Cells.Item(1).PasteSpecial() | Out-Null

$Footer = $Sheet.Cells.Item($(($Sheet.UsedRange.Rows)|Select -Last 1 -Expand Row)+1,1)
$Sheet.Rows.Item(1).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null
$Footer.Font.Bold = $True
$Footer.Value2 = "Folder Permissons Report"
```